# How can I select data from multiple JSON files and relate them?

Tags: json, angular, forms, angular11

I have a project in `Angular11` in which I have included two `JSON` files, one with the provinces and the other with the municipalities, both files related by the Id, (the Id of the provinces is concatenated to each of their municipalities).
I have created a `form` to select the province and depending on the chosen province, select one of the corresponding municipalities. I can select the province without problems, but I cannot show the municipalities.

This is my `component.html`:

```
<ng-container>
    <div class="formAdd">
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="10px">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
                <mat-label>Province</mat-label>
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let op of provinceArray;">
                        {{ op.nm }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
                <mat-label>Municipality</mat-label>
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option>
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

This is my `component.ts`:

```
import municipalityArray from "../municipality.json";
import provinceArray from "../province.json";

export class SidenavAutosizeExample {
  selectedProvince = provinceArray[0];
  provinceArray = provinceArray;

  constructor() {}
}
```

This is my `province.json`:

```
{
    "id": "24",
    "nm": "León"
},
{
    "id": "34",
    "nm": "Palencia"
}
```

This is my `municipality.json`:

```
{
    "id": "24007",
    "nm": "Arganza"
}, {
    "id": "24008",
    "nm": "Astorga"
}, {
    "id": "24009",
    "nm": "Balboa"
}, {
    "id": "24010",
    "nm": "Bañeza, La"
}, {
    "id": "34001",
    "nm": "Abarca de Campos"
}, {
    "id": "34003",
    "nm": "Abia de las Torres"
}, {
    "id": "34004",
    "nm": "Aguilar de Campoo"
}, {
    "id": "34005",
    "nm": "Alar del Rey"
}
```

**My problem**:
When I select a province I need the list of municipalities related to the selected province to be shown in the select of municipalities.

Each province has an ID (Leon - 24) and each municipality concatenates the ID of the province to which it belongs (Arganza - 24007).

You would need to collect the Id of the selected province, search the JSON for all the municipalities that start with that Id and show them in the select. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have the following example code with both JSON files: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-sidenav-example-4zr4yq?file=municipality.json

Comment: `mat-select` has an `selectionChange` output function https://material.angular.io/components/select/api You should use this function in your first select, and filter the content on the second select based on the value of the first one

Comment: Ok I just added selectionChange in the mat-select: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-sidenav-example-4zr4yq?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html . Now what I need is to be able to select the municipalities that belong to the selected province

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a work example here. [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/municipalities-provinces-mat-select?file=src/app/app.component.html)

1. make sure to have a clean json files:
   in my example I put the 2 lists in one single file.
2. Make a service *(api.service.ts)* to get all lists with observables
   and a helper to parse json data.

```
    const fromJson = data => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

3. **Init** your component form with a **FormGroup**
   in the axample I use **FormBuilder** to init formGroup.
4. get data for provinces with the api service
5. make an update method for municipalities list with params **province id**
6. use **selectionChange** of mat-select to update and get municipalities list data,
   I add a **prId** in the model of the province to match filter.

Comment: Is there a way to take the first two digits of the Id instead of creating the prId in the municipalities? I mean, could you do something like this ?: ``const id = parseInt(muns.id.toString().substring(0, 2));``

Comment: I edit the code in the same Stakblitz project. I change this method.
`getMunicipalitiesByProvinceId = (id: string): Observable<Municipality[]> => {

    const takeTwoFirstDigit = (str: string) =>  str.substring(0,2)

    const muns: Observable<Municipality[]> = of(fromJson(data).municipalities);
    return muns.pipe(map(values => values.filter(mun => takeTwoFirstDigit(mun.id) === id)));
  };`

Comment: Ok ok I adapted it without using MatSelectChange for Angular 11 and it works fine, thanks. As a curiosity, would it be possible to add a search field in the select municipalities to be able to search by name instead of seeing the whole list?

Comment: I edit the code once again, With no use of **selectionChange** , add a filter as first option in municipalities mat-select. filtering by  startsWith.

Comment: Ok, I understand the process to search, the problem is that I think that the onChange function should not be eliminated, because when you change the Province, the list of municipalities is not updated, the list of the first Province selected follows. You can see that the id of the municipalities does not change when the province is updated. Anyway, I thought there was a simpler way for Angular 11, like a simple label or a reactive forms function.

Comment: No, the **take** operator in line 75  I missed to delete it. now you can have your behavior expected.